# What is an auditory upward sweep?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology, hearing, human-ear

I was reading an article in nature communications, when I came across this sentence: "The ‘match’ rule was indicated by either a blue circle or a auditory upward sweep".So I tried googling what was an upward sweep, and came across this: "natural and complex vocalizations consist of basic elements such as upward sweeps, downward sweeps, constant frequency components, amplitude modulations..." I don't understand this. Can someone explain what is an upward sweep?

Here is the link to the article: http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/131128/ncomms3878/abs/ncomms3878.html,

But I think you have to pay to view the whole article, so here is another link that discusses the findings of the article:

http://www.uni-tuebingen.de/en/landingpage/newsfullview-landingpage/article/von-wegen-spatzenhirn-wie-nervenzellen-schlaues-verhalten-bei-rabenvoegeln-ermoeglichen.html

Comment: You should provide a link to the article.

Comment: Yes definitely include the article link. It sounds to me that the authors used a sound that started at a low frequency and increased in pitch over time.

Comment: It just means a sound that starts at a low frequency and goes up to higher frequency like a whistle sound. Perhaps someone can give you an example sound file and/or a spectrogram representation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from my comment:

It just means a sound that starts at a low frequency and goes up to a higher frequency like a whistle sound. Perhaps someone can give you an example sound file and/or a spectrogram representation of it.

Comment: http://jn.physiology.org/content/jn/94/2/1299/F2.large.jpg